# Finding zeros of equation using python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to write code that will find n, in this equation.

[image: function]

with the rest as user defined variables.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.stats import t

def f(alpha, beta, sigma, delta, eps):
    n = ((t.ppf(1-alpha,2*n-2) + t.ppf((1-beta)/2,2*n-2))**2*sigma**2)/(2*      (delta-abs(eps))**2)
```

I'd also like to be able to set up different scenarios of parameters and then have it output a table of the parameters and the results (e.g., input alpha1, alpha2, beta1, beta2 etc. and get out [alpha1, beta1,..., n],[alpha1, beta2,...,n]). I'm not quite sure what the best way to do that would be if anyone can genrally point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your equation you are trying to find the number of observations (n) that satisfy the statistical test equation. If that is the case, then n are natural numbers (0, 1, 2..etc.) and are easily iterable.

You could set up a solver yourself, where you have n as the iterable and the equation with result as the "result" of your equation:

```
for n in range(0, 1000):
    result = your_function(n, other_parameters)
```

Then you simply need to check if the equation is satisfied by setting:

```
    if n >= result:
        print "result:", n
        break  # This will exit the loop
```

What comes to testing different user given parameters, you can set up another loop which iterates different values for alpha, beta and so on.